# grid search over multiple classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there  a better  inbuilt way to do grid search and test multiple models in a single pipeline? Of course the parameters of the models would be different, which made is complicated for me to figure this out. Here is what I did:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV


def grid_search():
    pipeline1 = Pipeline((
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier()),
    ('vec2', TfidfTransformer())
    ))

    pipeline2 = Pipeline((
    ('clf', KNeighborsClassifier()),
    ))

    pipeline3 = Pipeline((
    ('clf', SVC()),
    ))

    pipeline4 = Pipeline((
    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
    ))
    
    parameters1 = {
    'clf__n_estimators': [10, 20, 30],
    'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'clf__max_features': [5, 10, 15],
    'clf__max_depth': ['auto', 'log2', 'sqrt', None]
    }

    parameters2 = {
    'clf__n_neighbors': [3, 7, 10],
    'clf__weights': ['uniform', 'distance']
    }

    parameters3 = {
    'clf__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0],
    'clf__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly'],
    'clf__gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0],

    }
    parameters4 = {
    'clf__alpha': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0]
    }

    pars = [parameters1, parameters2, parameters3, parameters4]
    pips = [pipeline1, pipeline2, pipeline3, pipeline4]
    
    print "starting Gridsearch"
    for i in range(len(pars)):
        gs = GridSearchCV(pips[i], pars[i], verbose=2, refit=False, n_jobs=-1)
        gs = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print "finished Gridsearch"
        print gs.best_score_
```

However, this approach is still giving the best model within each classifier, and not comparing between classifiers.

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this.

Comment: yet ;) [the problem is that we can not set the "steps" of the pipeline, right?]

Comment: @AndreasMueller; sorry didn't address this earlier. Can you elaborate what you meant there ?

Comment: Well you can not switch the Pipeline steps using the parameter grid.

Comment: is this been changed/updated with this functionality?

Comment: The post [Hyperparameter Grid Search across multiple models in scikit-learn](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/23/model_optimization/) (by David S. Batista) offers an updated implementation of an `EstimatorSelectionHelper` estimator which can run different estimators, each with its own grid of parameters.

Comment: this solution worked best for my, I only had to do some small changes to run on Python3 and with the latest versions of scikit-learn 0.19, code is available here: http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/23/model_optimization/

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51629917/10161091) the answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using Grid Search for hyperparameter selection, you can use the ['hyperopt' library](https://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/).

Please have a look at section 2.2 of [this page](https://github.com/jaberg/hyperopt/wiki/FMin). In the above case, you can use an `hp.choice` expression to select among the various pipelines and then define the parameter expressions for each one separately.

In your objective function, you need to have a check depending on the pipeline chosen and return the CV score for the selected pipeline and parameters (possibly via [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)).

The trials object at the end of the execution, will indicate the best pipeline and parameters overall.

Answer (score 24):

Although the solution from dubek is more straight forward, it does not help with interactions between parameters of pipeline elements that come before the classfier. Therefore, I have written a [helper class](https://github.com/bmurauer/pipelinehelper) to deal with it, and can be included in the default Pipeline setting of scikit. A minimal example:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MaxAbsScaler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from pipelinehelper import PipelineHelper

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', PipelineHelper([
        ('std', StandardScaler()),
        ('max', MaxAbsScaler()),
    ])),
    ('classifier', PipelineHelper([
        ('svm', LinearSVC()),
        ('rf', RandomForestClassifier()),
    ])),
])

params = {
    'scaler__selected_model': pipe.named_steps['scaler'].generate({
        'std__with_mean': [True, False],
        'std__with_std': [True, False],
        'max__copy': [True],  # just for displaying
    }),
    'classifier__selected_model': pipe.named_steps['classifier'].generate({
        'svm__C': [0.1, 1.0],
        'rf__n_estimators': [100, 20],
    })
}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, scoring='accuracy', verbose=1)
grid.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.best_score_)
```

It can also be used for other elements of the pipeline, not just the classifier.
Code is on [github](https://github.com/bmurauer/pipelinehelper) if anyone wants to check it out.

Edit: I have published this on PyPI if anyone is interested, just install ti using `pip install pipelinehelper`.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I did it without a wrapper function.
You can evaluate any number of classifiers. Each one can have multiple parameters for hyperparameter optimization.

The one with best score will be saved to disk using pickle

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from operator import itemgetter
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import operator
```

```
#pipeline parameters
    parameters = \
        [ \
            {
                'clf': [MultinomialNB()],
                'tf-idf__stop_words': ['english', None],
                'clf__alpha': [0.001, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
            },

            {
                'clf': [SVC()],
                'tf-idf__stop_words': ['english', None],
                'clf__C': [0.001, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 10e5],
                'clf__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
                'clf__class_weight': ['balanced'],
                'clf__probability': [True]
            },

            {
                'clf': [DecisionTreeClassifier()],
                'tf-idf__stop_words': ['english', None],
                'clf__criterion': ['gini','entropy'],
                'clf__splitter': ['best','random'],
                'clf__class_weight':['balanced', None]
            }
        ]

    #evaluating multiple classifiers
    #based on pipeline parameters
    #-------------------------------
    result=[]

    for params in parameters:

        #classifier
        clf = params['clf'][0]

        #getting arguments by
        #popping out classifier
        params.pop('clf')

        #pipeline
        steps = [('tf-idf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('clf',clf)]

        #cross validation using
        #Grid Search
        grid = GridSearchCV(Pipeline(steps), param_grid=params, cv=3)
        grid.fit(features, labels)

        #storing result
        result.append\
        (
            {
                'grid': grid,
                'classifier': grid.best_estimator_,
                'best score': grid.best_score_,
                'best params': grid.best_params_,
                'cv': grid.cv
            }
        )

    #sorting result by best score
    result = sorted(result, key=operator.itemgetter('best score'),reverse=True)

    #saving best classifier
    grid = result[0]['grid']
    joblib.dump(grid, 'classifier.pickle')
```

Answer (score 6):

Another Simple solution to the problem.

First load all the estimators. Here I will be using classifiers mostly.

```
logi=LogisticRegression(penalty="elasticnet",l1_ratio=0.5,solver="saga", random_state=4, n_jobs=-1)
rf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=4, n_jobs=-1, max_features="auto", warm_start=True)
gb=GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=4, subsample=0.8, max_features="auto", warm_start=True)
svc=SVC(random_state=4, kernel='rbf')
ex=ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=4, n_jobs=-1, max_features="auto", warm_start=True)
```

After that create a list of classifiers:

```
ensemble_clf=[rf, ex, gb, svc]
```

Now, Create all parameters for each classifier/estimator:-

```
params1={"max_depth": range(5,30,5), "min_samples_leaf": range(1,30,2),
         "n_estimators":range(100,2000,200)}
params2={"criterion":["gini", "entropy"],"max_depth": range(5,30,5), 
         "min_samples_leaf": range(1,30,2), "n_estimators":range(100,2000,200)}
params3={"learning_rate":[0.001,0.01,0.1], "n_estimators":range(1000,3000,200)}
params4={"kernel":["rbf", "poly"], "gamma": ["auto", "scale"], "degree":range(1,6,1)}
```

Now create a list of them:

```
parameters_list=[params1, params2, params3, params4]
```

Now, comes the most important part:
Create a string names for all the models/classifiers or estimators:
This is used to create the **Dataframes** for **comparison**

```
model_log=["_rf", "_ex", "_gb", "_svc"]
```

Now run a for loop and use the Grid search:

```
for i in range(len(ensemble_clf)):
    Grid=GridSearchCV(estimator=ensemble_clf[i], param_grid=parameters_list[i], 
                      n_jobs=-1, cv=3, verbose=3).fit(TrainX_Std, TrainY)
    globals()['Grid%s' % model_log[i]]=pd.DataFrame(Grid.cv_results_)
```

The **"globals()['Grid%s' % model_log[i]]=pd.DataFrame(Grid.cv_results_)  "** will create dataframes individually for each of the estimators used and can be used to comparison by **Sorting** and picking up the best parameters of each and every estimator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Liked the approach - pretty neat. However, I would use a dict of models to make it more readable, and instead of creating data frames for every model grid search, **inside the for loop I 'd do a `Grid.best_estimator_` to get the best estimator found for a especific model :)** https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#best_estimator_

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [HyperclassifierSearch (Github)](https://github.com/dabln/HyperclassifierSearch) package. It is close to the solution of [bmurauer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48807797/3070843).

However, you might

1. find the DataFrame output for the best model helpful which skips timing info as the default
2. find the three [usage examples helpful](https://github.com/dabln/HyperclassifierSearch/blob/main/HyperclassifierSearch%20examples.ipynb)
3. like the shorter core code with around 100 lines

I developed the [HyperclassifierSearch package](https://pypi.org/project/HyperclassifierSearch/) (start with a `pip install HyperclassifierSearch`) based on the code from [David Batista](https://github.com/davidsbatista/machine-learning-notebooks/blob/master/hyperparameter-across-models.ipynb) which I liked for the conciseness of the code.

Detail for 1., usage of the hyperclassifier evaluate_model function:

```
search = HyperclassifierSearch(models, params)
best_model = search.train_model(X, y)
search.evaluate_model(sort_by='mean_test_score', show_timing_info=False) # default parameters explicitly given
```

Comment: how do you specify the scoring metric?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Re @Maths12, you can pass `scoring` as in sklearn gridsearchcv to the `train_model` method, e.g. `scoring=["f1", "precision"]`. If you pass a string it will work fine, but if you want to pass a list (as in my example) then the code needs a small change in `evaluate_model`.