# How do I change - using for loops to call multiple functions - into - using a pipeline to call a class?

Tags: python, for-loop, scikit-learn, pipeline

So the basic requirement is that, I get a dictionary of models from user, and a dictionary of their hyper parameters and give a report. Currently goal is for binary classification, but this can be extended later.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# import pandas_profiling as pp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, recall_score, precision_score, make_scorer
from sklearn import datasets
# import joblib
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = cancer.target
target = df['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns='target', axis=1), target, test_size=0.4, random_state=13, stratify=target)

def build_model(model_name, model_class, params=None):
    """
    return model instance
    """
    if 'Ridge' in model_name:
        model = model_class(penalty='l2')
    elif 'Lasso' in model_name:
        model = model_class(penalty='l1')
    elif 'Ensemble' in model_name:
        model = model_class(estimators=[('rf', RandomForestClassifier()), ('gbm', GradientBoostingClassifier())], voting='hard')
    else:
        model = model_class()

    if params is not None:
        print('Custom Model Parameters provided. Implementing Randomized Search for {} model'.format(model_name))
        rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=params[model_name],
                                  random_state=22, n_iter=10, cv=5, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1,
                                 scoring=make_scorer(f1_score), error_score=0.0)
        return rscv

    print('No model parameters provided. Using sklearn default values for {} model'.format(model_name))
    return model

def fit_model(model_name, model_instance, xTrain, yTrain):
    """
    fit model
    """
    if model_name == 'SVM':
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        model = model_instance.fit(scaler.fit_transform(xTrain), yTrain)
    else:
        model = model_instance.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

    return model

def predict_vals(fitted_model, xTest):
    """
    predict and return vals
    """
    if model_name == 'SVM':
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        y_prediction = fitted_model.predict(scaler.fit_transform(xTest))
    else:
        y_prediction = fitted_model.predict(xTest)

    return y_prediction

def get_metrics(yTest, y_prediction):
    """
    get metrics after getting prediction
    """
    return [recall_score(yTest, y_prediction),
            precision_score(yTest, y_prediction), 
            f1_score(yTest, y_prediction),
           roc_auc_score(yTest, y_prediction)]

def model_report(list_of_metrics):
    """
    add metrics to df, return df
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_metrics, columns=['Model', 'Recall', 'Precision', 'f1', 'roc_auc'])
    df = df.round(3)
    return df

models = {
    'Logistic Regression Ridge': LogisticRegression,
    'Logistic Regression Lasso': LogisticRegression,
    'Random Forest': RandomForestClassifier,
    'SVM': SVC,
    'GBM': GradientBoostingClassifier,
    'EnsembleRFGBM': VotingClassifier
}

model_parameters = {
    'SVM': {
        'C': np.random.uniform(50, 1, [25]),#[1, 10, 100, 1000],
        'class_weight': ['balanced'],
        'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001],
        'kernel': ['linear']
    },
    'Random Forest': {
        'n_estimators': [5, 10, 50, 100, 200],
        'max_depth': [3, 5, 10, 20, 40],
        'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'bootstrap': [True, False],
        'min_samples_leaf': [np.random.randint(1,10)]
    },
    'Logistic Regression Ridge': {
        'C': np.random.rand(25),
        'class_weight': ['balanced']
    },
    'Logistic Regression Lasso': {
        'C': np.random.rand(25),
        'class_weight': ['balanced']
    },
    'GBM': {
        'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 200, 500],
        'max_depth': [3, 5, 10, None],
        'min_samples_leaf': [np.random.randint(1,10)]
    },
    'EnsembleRFGBM': {
        'rf__n_estimators': [5, 10, 50, 100, 200],
        'rf__max_depth': [3, 5, 10, 20, 40],
        'rf__min_samples_leaf': [np.random.randint(1,10)],
        'gbm__n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 200, 500],
        'gbm__max_depth': [3, 5, 10, None],
        'gbm__min_samples_leaf': [np.random.randint(1,10)]
    }
}
```

Without parameters I get the following report.

```
# without parameters
lst = []
for model_name, model_class in models.items():
    model_instance = build_model(model_name, model_class)
    fitted_model = fit_model(model_name, model_instance, X_train, y_train)
    y_predicted = predict_vals(fitted_model, X_test)
    metrics = get_metrics(y_test, y_predicted)

    lst.append([model_name] + metrics)

model_report(lst)
```

[image]

With parameters given as input

```
# with parameters
lst = []
for model_name, model_class in models.items():
    model_instance = build_model(model_name, model_class, model_parameters)
    fitted_model = fit_model(model_name, model_instance, X_train, y_train)
    y_predicted = predict_vals(fitted_model, X_test)
    metrics = get_metrics(y_test, y_predicted)

    lst.append([model_name] + metrics)

model_report(lst)
```

[image]

The task given to me right now is as follows.

1. Take from user, a dictionary of models, and their parameters. If parameters are not provided, then use defaults of the models.
2. Give as output the report (as seen in images)

I was told that I should change the functions to classes. And avoid for loops if possible.

My challenges:

1. How do I change all the functions into a class and methods? Basically my senior wants something like

`report.getReport # gives the dataFrame of the report`

But the above sounds to me like it can be done in a function as follows (I don't understand why/how a class would be beneficial)

```
customReport(whatever inputs I'd like to give) # gives df of report
```

2. How do I avoid `for loops` to get through the user inputs for various models? What I thought was that I could use [sklearn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), since according to my understanding, pipeline is a series of steps, so from user take the params and models, and execute them as a series of steps. This avoids the for loops.

Something like this

```
customPipeline = Pipeline([ ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(with relevant params from params dict),
                             'SVC', SVC(with relevant params from params dict)) ] )
```

**Similar solution** I found is [here](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/23/model_optimization/) but I would like to avoid `for loops` as such.

**Another related solution**  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285973/pipeline-multiple-classifiers) is using a class which can switch between different models. But here I would require that the user be able to give option whether he wants to do Gridsearch/RandomizedSearch/CV/None. My thinking is that I use this class, then inherit this to another class which the user can give input to choose Gridsearch/RandomizedSearch/CV/None etc. I'm not sure if I'm thinking in the right direction.

---

**NOTE** A full working solution is desirable (would love it) but not mandatory. It is ok if your answer has a skeleton which can give me a direction how to proceed. I am ok with exploring and learning from it.

Comment: This question is too broad and unclear. In its current form its looking like a homework problem. Please reword this and add what you tried to achieve what is being asked from you. As a starter, you can look at [estimator design of scikit-learn here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimators).

Comment: Also, your current code will give wrong results for SVM because you are fitting a new `StandardScaler` on each call to prediction. Just as you save the model, you also need to save the scaler object during fitting. Thats where the pipeline will help you.

Comment: @VivekKumar (1) I am new to using python classes. At the time of posting I didn't have anything which I tried. Please look at my answer below for the working solution I have come up with. I think my solution explains better of what I wanted. Please feel free to edit my question/details for better wording in english.

(2) I understand and agree with you on `StandardScaler`. This was just a one off solution. There is a lot more to be improved on this. I am new to using `sklearn` so I am still learning things.

Comment: @VivekKumar `In its current form its looking like a homework problem` I cannot attest to that, this is an assignment given to me as a junior developer, homework or not, my point is to learn to solve problems. I apologize if this came off as **solve my homework**. That was not my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a working solution. I should have worded my question better. I initially misunderstood how `GridsearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV` works internally. `cv_results_` gives all the results of the grid available. I thought only the `best estimator` was available to us.

Using this, for each type of model, I took the max `rank_test_score`, and got the parameters making up the model. In this example, it is 4 models. Now I ran each of those models, i.e. the best combination of parameters for each model, with my test data, and predicted the required scores. I think this solution can be extended to `RandomizedSearchCV` and a lot more other options.

NOTE: This is just a trivial solution. Lot of modifications necessary, like needing to scale data for specific models, etc. This solution will just serve as a starting point which can be modified according to the user's needs.

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926120/5675288) for the `ClfSwitcher() class`.

Following is the implementation of the class (suggestions to improve are welcomed).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, recall_score, precision_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = cancer.target
target = df['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns='target', axis=1), target, test_size=0.4, random_state=13, stratify=target)

class ClfSwitcher(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, model=RandomForestClassifier()):
        """
        A Custom BaseEstimator that can switch between classifiers.
        :param estimator: sklearn object - The classifier
        """ 

        self.model = model


    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.model.fit(X, y)
        return self


    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        return self.model.predict(X)


    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self.model.predict_proba(X)

    def score(self, X, y):
        return self.estimator.score(X, y)

class report(ClfSwitcher):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.grid = None
        self.full_report = None
        self.concise_report = None
        self.scoring_metrics = {
            'precision': precision_score,
            'recall': recall_score,
            'f1': f1_score,
            'roc_auc': roc_auc_score
        }


    def griddy(self, pipeLine, parameters, **kwargs):
        self.grid = GridSearchCV(pipeLine, parameters, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)


    def fit_grid(self, X_train, y_train=None, **kwargs):
        self.grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    def make_grid_report(self):
        self.full_report = pd.DataFrame(self.grid.cv_results_)

    @staticmethod
    def get_names(col):
        return col.__class__.__name__

    @staticmethod
    def calc_score(col, metric):
        return round(metric(y_test, col.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)), 4)


    def make_concise_report(self):
        self.concise_report = pd.DataFrame(self.grid.cv_results_)
        self.concise_report['model_names'] = self.concise_report['param_cst__model'].apply(self.get_names)
        self.concise_report = self.concise_report.sort_values(['model_names', 'rank_test_score'], ascending=[True, False]) \
                                                .groupby(['model_names']).head(1)[['param_cst__model', 'model_names']] \
                                                .reset_index(drop=True)

        for metric_name, metric_func in self.scoring_metrics.items():
            self.concise_report[metric_name] = self.concise_report['param_cst__model'].apply(self.calc_score, metric=metric_func)

        self.concise_report = self.concise_report[['model_names', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1', 'roc_auc', 'param_cst__model']]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ClfSwitcher()),
])

parameters = [
    {
        'cst__model': [RandomForestClassifier()],
        'cst__model__n_estimators': [10, 20],
        'cst__model__max_depth': [5, 10],
        'cst__model__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [SVC()],
        'cst__model__C': [10, 20],
        'cst__model__kernel': ['linear'],
        'cst__model__gamma': [0.0001, 0.001]
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [LogisticRegression()],
        'cst__model__C': [13, 17],
        'cst__model__penalty': ['l1', 'l2']
    },
    {
        'cst__model': [GradientBoostingClassifier()],
        'cst__model__n_estimators': [10, 50],
        'cst__model__max_depth': [3, 5],
        'cst__model__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2]
    }
]

my_report = report()
my_report.griddy(pipeline, parameters, scoring='f1')
my_report.fit_grid(X_train, y_train)
my_report.make_concise_report()
my_report.concise_report
```

Output Report as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using map(), details here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Some programmers have the habit of avoiding raw loops - "A raw loop is any loop inside a function where the function serves purpose larger than the algorithm
implemented by the loop". More details here: https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf

I think that's the reason you are asked to remove for loop.

Comment: I have added a working solution. Please have a look at it and let me know if you have any suggestions. :)